# PHP simple array manipulation for filtering common keys

Tags: php, arrays

I know it's simple task, but my mind not clicking at present for appropriate solution.

I have 2 arrays

```
$array1=Array
(
    [302] => Array
        (
            [id] => 302
            [medical_id] => 55
            [medication_name] => disprin
            [medication_frequency] => 1
            [medication_status] => Stoped
            [users_id] => 106
            [update_date] => 2012-03-02 11:03:57
        )

)

$array2=Array
(
    [302] => Array
        (
            [medication_id] => 302
            [id] => 14
            [medical_id] => 55
            [medication_name] => disprin
            [medication_frequency] => 2
            [medication_status] => Stoped
            [users_id] => 106
            [update_date] => 2012-03-02 11:03:57
            [change_date] => 
        )

    [305] => Array
        (
            [medication_id] => 305
            [id] => 15
            [medical_id] => 57
            [medication_name] => disprin
            [medication_frequency] => 2
            [medication_status] => Continued
            [users_id] => 106
            [update_date] => 2012-03-02 11:02:46
            [change_date] => 
        )

)
```

I want Output:

```
$outputarray=Array
(
      [302] => Array
        (
            [id] => 302
            [medical_id] => 55
            [medication_name] => disprin
            [medication_frequency] => 1
            [medication_status] => Stoped
            [users_id] => 106
            [update_date] => 2012-03-02 11:03:57
        )

    [305] => Array
        (
            [medication_id] => 305
            [id] => 15
            [medical_id] => 57
            [medication_name] => disprin
            [medication_frequency] => 2
            [medication_status] => Continued
            [users_id] => 106
            [update_date] => 2012-03-02 11:02:46
            [change_date] => 
        )

)
```

means if same key is exist in array1 then take it from array1 else from array2.

I tried with some PHP functions like `array_merge`,`array_merge_recursive` but not got desired output.

am not able to recollect memory now, Please suggest me any PHP array function to  sort out this.

Comment: Have you tried combination of different array_* functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's so simple that it's almost unethical:

```
$outputArray = $array1 + $array2;
```

Array [union](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) (above) does what you describe. Using `array_merge` could also work in general, but not directly with such input because your keys are integers.

Comment: What's unethical is that this answer isn't CW ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 0):

Check with in_array() & store using array_push() will be a solution for you.